# jQuery filter with imputs (include / inside checkbox)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, checkbox, filter

I would like to ask if anyone knows how to solve my problem. Filtering works for every other (**I want to use case insensitive**), but the **checkbox does not appear after searching** for "food". I need to create a list of categories with checkboxes. If you search for a category, you can immediately check the checkbox

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myDIV *").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Filter</h2>
<!--Type something in the input field to search for a specific text inside the div element with id="myDIV" -->
<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">

<div id="myDIV">
  <p>dog</p>
  <div>master20</div>
  <button>Button</button>
  <p>Welcome5</p>
  <label class="important_class_for_me">Food
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="my_custom_checkmark"></span>
  </label>
</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That very loose structure is not very conducive to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is character `*`, selector `$("#myDIV *")`. By specifying this character you are referring to all children as `parent - child - child - child ...`.

You only need to reference the first child of parent `#myDIV`. Replace `*` with `>`. Like that:

```
$("#myDIV >").filter(function() { ... }
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myInput").on("keyup", function () {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#myDIV >").filter(function () {
            $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Filter</h2>
<!--Type something in the input field to search for a specific text inside the div element with id="myDIV" -->
<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search.." />

<div id="myDIV">
    <p>dog</p>
    <div>master20</div>
    <button>Button</button>
    <p>Welcome5</p>
    <label class="important_class_for_me">
        Food
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <span class="my_custom_checkmark"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are hiding every element inside myDIV, not only the intimidate child.

it happens that :

```
<input type="checkbox">
<span class="my_custom_checkmark"></span>
```

both are child and they do not have **.text()** so they will toggle.

Instead, just do the filter by the intimidate child by changing  `$("#myDIV *")` to `$("#myDIV > *")`